# MySQL Loop UPDATE data from GET

Tags: mysql

hope you have a good day.

I want to create procedure and set events (already done) in MySQL, the procedure is

```
:loop
UPDATE tableB
SET Status='Ex-'
WHERE (id = '($data_from_get)'))
:endloop
```

and the GET ($data_from_get) query is

```
SELECT id from tableA
WHERE ('out_date' > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

i just don't know how to store all GET value from tableA and make UPDATE loop to tableB like `foreach $data_from_get as $data_from get, do UPDATE`

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the IN operator with a subquery? I'm not following the loop stuff.

Answer (score 0):

this might works

```
UPDATE tableB AS b,  tableA AS a
SET a.status = 'Ex-'
WHERE (b.out_date > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')) AND (a.id=b.id)
```